# заполнить ListView с использованием SimpleCursorAdapter и CursorLoader

Tags: android, listview

Мне нужно реализовать заполнение `ListView` из БД, для чего я использовал пример, взятый из урока 136 на сайте startandroid.ru.
`ListView` у меня находится не в активити, а в фрагменте и почему-то не заполняется данными из БД. БД не пустая (я проверил).
При этом если разместить `ListView` в активити, то все прекрасно работает...

DB.java:

```
    public class DB {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "myDB";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE = "db_table";


    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TXT = "txt";
    public static final String COLUMN_STR = "number_s";

    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + TABLE + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    COLUMN_TXT + " text," +
                    COLUMN_STR + " text" +
                    ");";


    private final Context mCtx;


    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }

    // открыть подключение
    public void open() {
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // закрыть подключение
    public void close() {
        if (mDBHelper != null)
            mDBHelper.close();
    }

    // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
    public void addRec(String txt, String numb) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_TXT, txt);
        cv.put(COLUMN_STR, numb);
        mDB.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
    public void delRec(long id) {
        mDB.delete(TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    // класс по созданию и управлению БД
    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
                + DB_NAME;

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        // создаем и заполняем БД
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            // Создаём новый экземпляр таблицы
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.liashenkov.listtraining.fragments.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Fragment1.OnSelectedItemListener {


    Fragment mFragment1, mFragment2;
    boolean isPortret;

    private FragmentTransaction mTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        isPortret = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.port);

        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        mFragment1 =  mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);

        mTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            mTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, mFragment1);
        } else {
            if (isPortret) {
                mTransaction.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2));
            }
        }
        if (!isPortret) {

        mFragment2 =  mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        mTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment2, mFragment2);
        }
        mTransaction.commit();
    }

        @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int buttonIndex) {

            mTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, mFragment2);
        }
}
```

Fragment1.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"

    android:layout_weight="0.95"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add item"
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"/>
```

Fragment1.java:

```
     public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment implements View.OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private static final String TAG = "{fragment}";
    String mTextToList;
    String  mNumber;
    Button mAddbutton;

    DB db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;

    public Fragment1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        db = new DB (getActivity());
        db.open();

        mAddbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mAddbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_TXT, DB.COLUMN_STR};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvText, R.id.tvNumber };

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);

       setListAdapter(scAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        mTextToList = "Some text";
        mNumber = String.valueOf(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));


            // добавляем запись
        db.addRec(mTextToList, mNumber);

          // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
          getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();       
    }

     public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // закрываем подключение при выходе
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }

    public interface OnSelectedItemListener {
        void onItemSelected(int buttonIndex);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в разметке Fragment1.xml `ListView` назначьте `android:layout_weight="1" , `android:layout_height="0dp"` , а `Button`  веса не назначайте вовсе. Так им будет лучше

Answer (score 1):

Всем большое спасибо за ответы и уделенное внимание! Моя ошибка закралась в реализации метода onLoadFinished(). Он получал курсор из значением null, так как переменная Cursor cursor была объявлена, но не инициализирована. И вообще ей там не место. 
Вот так работает:

```
    @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(data);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, после того, как вы в **ListFragment** переназначаете разметку в **onCreateView**() фрагмент более не может найти **ListView**, коему надо адаптер назначить.

Мой совет - не пользовать **ListFragment** (ибо скрытая реализация простейших действий должна смущать), а просто Fragment, в коем найти **ListView** и ему назначить адаптер.

Либо поройтесь в методах **ListFragment** и найдите там как назначить его список тому, коий вы в разметке добавили.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю причина в том, что асинхронный поток `CursorLoader` не успевает выбрать данные и на момент привязки адаптера к списку они еще отсутствуют.
Привязывайте адаптер после гарантированной выборки курсора, скажем в методе `onLoadFinished()` класса `CursorLoader`:

**Fragment1.java**

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

  String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_TXT, DB.COLUMN_STR};
  int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvText, R.id.tvNumber };
  scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, data, from, to, 0);
  setListAdapter(scAdapter);
}
```

Ну а из `onCreateView()` все, что перенесли нужно, естественно, убрать.

Так же, в разметке фрагмента присваивать идентификатор `ListView` нужно таким образом  (Fragment1.xml) :

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```